How to catch exception in a timer that has a loop and continue iterating next time?
I have a class that use a PeriodicTimer.
The code of the timer is a loop that iterates some items.
If there is no problem, I iterate next item, and if some item throw an exception, I would like to iterate the next item.
When the loop is finished, I would like to throw an AggregateException with all the exceptions.
Another class uses this class, and will receive the exceptions and it will handle it, logging it in a text file.
I was trying a code something like that:
internal class TimerClass
{
    public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            while (await _timer.WaitForNextTickAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                List<Exception> exceptions = [];

                foreach (Fichero iterator in _someItems)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //do something
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        exceptions.Add(ex);
                    }
                }

                throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}

public class MainClass
{
    private readonly TimerClass _timer;

    public AplicacionGestorDatos()
    {
        _timer = CreateTimerClass();
    }

    private void DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            _timer.DoSomethingAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //log exceptions
        }
    }
}

The problem is that if the aggregate exception is thrown, the timer will not continue more in the next time.
I was thinking that the TimerClass cloud define an event to notify exceptions, something like this:
internal class TimerClass
{
    public delegate void ExceptionHappenedEventHandler(Exception paramException);

    public event ExceptionHappenedEventHandler ExceptionEvent;
    private void OnExceptionHappened(Exception paramException)
    {
        ExceptionEvent?.Invoke(paramException);
    }

    public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
            while (await _timer.WaitForNextTickAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                foreach (Fichero iteradorFicheroSolicitado in _equipo.Ficheros)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Do somthing
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        OnExceptionHappened("Some error happens");
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

public class mainClass
{
    private readonly TimerClass _timerClass;

    public MainClass()
    {
        _timerClass = create timer
        _timer.ExceptionEvent += ExceptionHappenedInTimerClassEventHandler;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _timerClass.DoSomethingAsync();
    }

    private void ExceptionHappenedInTimerClassEventHandler(Exception paramException)
    {
        //log the excepton
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer.ExceptionEvent -= ExceptionHappenedInTimerClassEventHandler;
    }
}

But I was wondering if there would be a simpler solution, instead to have to define events in the timer class.
Thanks.

Another alternative could be injecting an Action in the timer, containing the error handling logic. You can do that via constructor injection for instance and invoke the delegate in the catch block.

Your code includes things that are a waste of space, like the extraneous try { } catch { throw; } block, and is missing things that are important, like checking if the exceptions is non-empty before throwing the AggregateException. Please edit the code and remove what is unimportant, and add what is crucial. And make sure that your code compiles before posting it.

Also please rethink the name of your class. The TimerClass uses a timer, but it's not a timer. It's a processor. Things should be named according to what they are, not what they use internally.
